# Laravel - Element displaying twice while looping inside a condition

Tags: laravel, if-statement, laravel-5, eloquent, while-loop

[This is the example while looping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rbmsh.jpg)

despite having a condition and relation many too many it seems that the case

```
  @foreach (\App\ClientDocument::where('id_client', $clients->id)->get() as $item)    
                  @if (\App\Document::where('id',$item->id_document)->get())
                  <a class="img-fluid " href="{{asset('images/'.$item->file)}}" download="{{asset('images/'.$item->file)}}" alt="" name="download"  > Telecharger </a>
            
                  @endif  
               @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

in the above snippet

```
@foreach (\App\ClientDocument::where('id_client', $clients->id)->get() as $item)    
                  @if (\App\Document::where('id',$item->id_document)->get())
                  <a class="img-fluid " href="{{asset('images/'.$item->file)}}" download="{{asset('images/'.$item->file)}}" alt="" name="download"  > Telecharger </a>
            
                  @endif  
               @endforeach
```

code is absolutely fine, but there might be the possibility, you are running with duplicate data, you can use this also.

```
\App\ClientDocument::where('id_client', $clients->id)->distinct('id_client')->get()
```

and instead of using  `@if (\App\Document::where('id',$item->id_document)->get())`

you can use
`@if (\App\Document::where('id',$item->id_document)->firstOrFail())`
`@if (\App\Document::where('id',$item->id_document)->count())`

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

first you shouldn't loading data inside blade files
do it inside controller function
then you should create relationship inside ClientDocument model name document
and in your blade you can do that
$item->document
or whatever you want

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).